# ¿Cómo puedo buscar la mejor coincidencia en mi tabla a partir de una frase introducida por un usuario?

Tags: mysql, mysqli, regex, mariadb

Tengo una tabla con dos campos y cien mil registros de posibles respuestas a una pregunta de un usuario.

Necesito lograr buscar una coincidencia en el patrón de pregunta que tengo guardada en mi columna pregunta con la frase que el cliente ha proporcionado.

Ejemplo sería:

```
columna pregunta1 = * hola * como estas * 
columna respuesta1 = yo muy bien y tu.

columna pregunta1 = * como estas * amigo *
columna respuesta1 = yo bien gracias y tu.

frase del cliente= "hola que tal amigo como estas. podemos blablabla";
```

Como ven, la primera pregunta de mi base de datos coincide más con la frase del cliente que la segunda, ya que tienen agregado la palabra "amigo".

He intentado crear algo así:

```
select "Hola max, como estás, te deseo feliz navidad" REGEXP ("[^*.][:como:][^*.][:est.*:][.*$]");
```

como acotación debe ser desde mysql porque quiero que sea portable a cualquier lenguaje.

Comment: Algo así te sirve?: `select lower("Hola max, como estas, te deseo feliz navidad") REGEXP ('^.*[[:<:]]c[oó]mo[\\t ]+[[:<:]]est');`

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo no 'inventar' tu propio lenguaje de expresiones regulares como el que utilizas aquí:

```
* hola * como estas *
```

Ya que al final cualquier solución pasará por "convertirlo" a un lenguaje de expresiones regulares más común.

Así pues, lo que haría, puesto que te interesa guardar un mapeo de preguntas con respuestas en bbdd, sería almacenar las preguntas ya con el formato de expresiones regulares soportado por mysql.

Para tu caso parece que simplemente con `\b` y `.*` podrías adaptar las preguntas

`\b` Significa barrera de palabra, es decir que si buscamos `\bpata\b` encontraríamos `pata` pero no `patata`

`.*` significa cualquier caracter 0 o más veces

Así pues, para los ejemplos que has puesto, los podrías almacenar así en bbdd (ten en cuenta que las contrabarras se han de escapar al insertarse en bbdd)

```
\\bhola\\b.*\\bcomo estas\\b.*
\\bcomo estas\\b.*\\bamigo\\b
```

Después, la query quedaría algo así:

```
select respuesta
from preguntas_respuestas
where regexp_like("como estas amigo bla bla",
                  pregunta);
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2QRMv92PautexiMavVdGUw/0) para que veas cómo funciona

Finalmente, te adjunto la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax) donde podrás ver la sintaxis admitida por mysql en las expresiones regulares.

Con las expresiones regulares soportadas por mysql, podrías progresar con tus requisitos. Si en algún momento se te queda corto, podrías pensar en utilizar MariaDB en lugar de mysql. MariaDB soporta PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions), con lo que podría conseguir búsquedas de patrones más complejas.

Finalmente, comentar que cuando insertes las preguntas en la bbdd, algunos caracteres se tendrán que escapar previamente.

Por ejemplo, si insertas la pregunta `Hola.` y buscar `Hola!` te lo encontraría, porque el punto `.` en expresiones regulares significa cualquier caracter. Así que a la hora de guardar la pregunta deberías guadarla así: `Hola\.`